# KeyError: Backslash in Python Dictionary Key

Tags: python, dictionary, backslash, keyerror

I am trying in Python to retrieve values from a dictionary created with json.loads() from the .text of a requests object which uses:

```
'\/'
```

as a separator in some of the dictionary keys. The dictionary is the standard output from another program not under my control.

If I try using:

```
dictionary['text\/text']
```

It generates a KeyError and says that there is no

```
'text\\/text'
```

key. Notice the double backslash it inserted.

I have tried:

```
r'text\/text', 'text\\/text', 'text'+chr(92)+chr(47)+'text', etc
```

I can't seem to get this to work. There's got to be some way to do this without having to parse the text of the entire dictionary and replace all occurrences of '/'. Any ideas?

edit: This was a stupid mistake on my part. I was reading the key values from the request.text, in which an extra backslash was printed before the forward slash. Martijn Pieters' comment hit straight home to the problem.

Comment: What does `dictionary.keys()` print?

Comment: The representation of the key uses a double slash because Python always escapes escape codes when echoing a string back to you. The value is entirely correct.

Comment: Have you tried `'text/text'` yet?

Comment: Martjin Pieters, thank you. You figured it out. I assumed that the original source was using '\/' as a separator, but it was actually using '/' and Python was inserting the '\' in the representation.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if there was a backslash in the printed representation, since forward slashes aren't considered special. Where did you see the backslash?

Comment: @user3229320: That would not be Python inserting that slash, actually. But *something* is inserting it, apparently.

Comment: I see the double backslash when I print the .text of the requests object. I had a gigantic brain fart in not trying .keys() earlier. It's a nested dictionary and for some reason I just didn't try it. .keys() on the inner dict shows a single '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in Idle (2.7.6) and it looks valid:

```
>>> d={'text\/text':'test'}
>>> d
{'text\\/text': 'test'}
>>> d['text\/text']
'test'
>>>
```

Comment: But that doesn't really help OP's problem.

Comment: @jmu303: Yeah, I was trying to reproduce the problem, and found I could not, so I thought that might be valuable.  I see where you're coming from though, I'm just not sure how to make my attempted answer (more) constructive.